# Spring creating bean without proxy

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, cglib

In my some project I run into problem. Annotation `@Transactional` in some classes didn't work. After restarted module annotation is work. I open class in debug and saw that the CGLIB proxy is not used in the class, and used if I restart module without changes! 
Eventually the problem was because project has custom library when in some class in `@PostConstruct` was registered beans duplicates of my beans with `beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition()` and after bean override in the part time class work without proxy. But I can't understand why? Why Spring create/ or replace/ or use bean without CGLIB proxy? 
I was fixed that in my context, but I don't understand.